# Expanding and collapsing child rows in Shiny DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, shiny, datatables-1.10

I'm having trouble replicating a datatable object in Shiny. Currently, I can display what I want when I run the data table portion of the code outside of a Shiny environment. However, when I run the entire code, it's not displaying the child table.

```
library(DT)
library(data.table)
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
 ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')),
 server = function(input, output) {
 output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(

  datatable({
    #Transform dataframe to data.table and turn the dataframe rowname into a data.table column called model
    mtcars_dt = data.table(mtcars)
    mtcars_dt[["model"]] = rownames(mtcars)
    setcolorder(mtcars_dt,c(
      which(colnames(mtcars_dt) %in% c("mpg","cyl","model")),
      which(!colnames(mtcars_dt) %in% c("mpg","cyl","model"))
    ))

    #Turn data table into a nested data.table by mpg, cyl
    mtcars_dt <- mtcars_dt[, list(cars=list(.SD)), by = list(mpg,cyl)]


    #configure datatable. Hide row number and cars columns [0,4] and enable details control on plus sign column[1]
    #turn rows into child rows and remove from parent
    cbind(' ' = '&oplus;', mtcars_dt)}, 

    escape = -2,
    options = list(
      columnDefs = list(
        list(visible = FALSE, targets = c(0,4)),
        list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = 1)
      )
    ),
    callback = JS("
                  table.column(1).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});

                  // Format cars object into another table
                  var format = function(d) {
                  if(d != null){ 
                  var result = ('<table id=\"child_' + d[2] + '_' + d[3] + '\">').replace('.','_') + '<thead><tr>'
                  for (var col in d[4]){
                  result += '<th>' + col + '</th>'
                  }
                  result += '</tr></thead></table>'
                  return result
                  }else{
                  return '';
                  }
                  }

                  var format_datatable = function(d) {
                  var dataset = [];
                  for (i = 0; i < + d[4]['model'].length; i++) {
                  var datarow = [];
                  for (var col in d[4]){
                  datarow.push(d[4][col][i])
                  }
                  dataset.push(datarow)
                  }
                  var subtable = $(('table#child_' + d[2] + '_' + d[3]).replace('.','_')).DataTable({
                  'data': dataset,
                  'autoWidth': true, 
                  'deferRender': true, 
                  'info': false, 
                  'lengthChange': false, 
                  'ordering': true, 
                  'paging': false, 
                  'scrollX': false, 
                  'scrollY': false, 
                  'searching': false 
                  });
                  };

                  table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
                  var td = $(this), row = table.row(td.closest('tr'));
                  if (row.child.isShown()) {
                  row.child.hide();
                  td.html('&oplus;');
                  } else {
                  row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                  td.html('&CircleMinus;');
                  format_datatable(row.data())
                  }
                  });")
      )
    )
  }
)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The key here seemed to be the difference between an object and an array. When using shiny, `row.data()` is an array and its fifth element is an array as well (here I clicked on the second row in the main table):

```
["2", "&oplus;", 22.8, 4, Array(2)]
```

Outside of the shiny environment, `row.data()` looks like this:

```
["2", "&oplus;", 22.8, 4, Object]
```

As you can see, the fifth element is an object! Why this is the case, I cannot tell. I guess there might be a difference in the versions of the libraries used behind the scenes.

To get this working we need to make 2 changes:

**1. Change `format()`:**

---

```
var format = function(d) {
  if(d != null) { 
    var result = ('<table id=\"child_' + d[2] + '_' + d[3] + '\">').replace('.','_') + '<thead><tr>'
    for (var col in d[4][0]) {
       result += '<th>' + col + '</th>'
    }
    result += '</tr></thead></table>'
    return result
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}
```

Here we just added `[0]` in line 4. As shown above, `d[4]` is an array. In case of the second row of data it consists of 2 objects. `(var col in d[4])` would return `0` and `1` (indices of the objects) whereas `(var col in d[4][0])` returns the elements of the first object (so the column names).

**2. Change `format_datatable()`:**

---

```
var format_datatable = function(d) {
  var dataset = [];
  for (i = 0; i <=  d[4].length-1; i++) {
    var datarow = $.map(d[4][i], function(value, index) {
      return [value];
    });
    dataset.push(datarow);
  }
  //  ...
  //  the rest did not change
}
```

Here we convert each car model (so each element in `d[4]`), which is represented as an object, into an array using `$.map()`. After that we just add this array to `dataset`.

The code that creates the subtable expects these arrays. Data is handled differently by DataTables with respect to its type which can be checked [here](https://datatables.net/manual/data/).